# Rails Server Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle-install

When i start my Rail Server for Project it gives an error like

```
sahil@sahil-M:~/sites/tasks$ rails s
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

and while i go for bundle install it giver another error

```
sahil@sahil-M:~/sites/tasks$ sudo bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.8)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.8)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.3)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Installing tzinfo (0.3.28)
Using actionpack (3.0.8)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.1)
Using treetop (1.4.9)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.8)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.8)
Using activeresource (3.0.8)
Using bundler (1.0.15)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.8)
Using rails (3.0.8)
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
from extconf.rb:3


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13
from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Comment: If my answer didn't help, can you share the next problem?

Comment: sahil@sahil-M:~/sites/tasks$ sudo su
    root@sahil-M:/home/sahil/sites/tasks# apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    ruby1.8-dev is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    root@sahil-M:/home/sahil/sites/tasks# exit
    exit
    sahil@sahil-M:~/sites/tasks$ rails s
    Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev libsqlite3-ruby libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `ruby1.8-dev` package as needed on your distro.

On Ubuntu/Debian, login as root on the console and install it like that:

```
apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

Or it might be just `ruby-dev`. Try it if `ruby1.8-dev` doesn't work.

Comment: `sahil@sahil-M:~/sites/tasks$ sudo su
    root@sahil-M:/home/sahil/sites/tasks# apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    ruby1.8-dev is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    root@sahil-M:/home/sahil/sites/tasks# exit
    exit
    sahil@sahil-M:~/sites/tasks$ rails s
    Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`